# Android Multithreadedness

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am attempting to make an Android app that connects to a server (through a `Socket`), and I believe I need to do it in a different thread. However, apparently, I can't access or modify the Android UI from another thread. What should I do?

```
package me.nrubin29.quiz.student;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Connection {

    private Socket socket;
    private Thread reader;
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream;

    public void initConnection(final Activity activity, final String ip, final String port, final String name) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Starting connection to " + ip + ":" + Integer.parseInt(port), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    socket = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));

                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                    outputStream.writeObject(name);

                    reader = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            while (true) {
                                try {
                                    Object in = inputStream.readObject();
                                    System.out.println(in);
                                }
                                catch (EOFException e) { Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    reader.start();
                }
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `runOnUiThread` which is a method of your activity class

Comment: So whenever I want to do *anything* GUI related, I should use that method?

Comment: More info here; https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: @Raghunandan Using runOnUiThread() works just fine. Thanks! If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @PogoStick29 i just did. if it helps go ahead and accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `runOnUiThread`

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
{
   @Override
   public void run() 
   { 
              // update ui
   }
});
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

```
public final void runOnUiThread (Runnable action)

Added in API level 1
Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

Parameters
action  the action to run on the UI thread
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `runOnUiThread` in the `Activity` you're passing in. This will post a message to the UI thread. Just keep in mind that you should never ever post a message to your UI thread that takes too long to execute, or it will lock your app and Android will prompt the user to force close it; that is, no network connections or heavy calculations.


An example:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    { 
          // Your UI stuff here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of dealing with "multithreadedness" in Android, and your approach may vary accordingly to your necessity.

Let's say you just use a simple java thread and have a reference to your activity (like the example provided), you can just call activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable r) and pass in the runnable that is going to update your UI. This actually puts the runnable to be executed after other ui events (like a animation, for example).

Another simple way to deal with it is to call "final Handler handler = new Handler()" in your Activity and pass this handler reference to the Thread. The Handler is one special object that is binded with the UI thread of your activity (when called from it) and can provide some methods to also post runnables from a background thread to the ui thread.

Yet another way is to use the AsyncTask, that is a simple object that gives you the ability to do something on the ui thread before your processing (like displaying a loading dialog), then do your processing on a background thread and then do something on your main thread again with the results of the background processing. This cicle is onPreExecute() -> doInBackground() -> onPostExecute().

There are also other approaches, depending on your needs.

Please beware of a few things:

Activities have a well defined life cycle, and they may (or may not) die before your background processing happens. You may (or may not) need to define some mechanism to check if the activity is still alive when you try to update its UI or you will get in trouble. AsyncTask have a really useful feature for accepting cancellation based on your activity onDestroy(), that is simply calling "cancel" on the AsyncTask on the activity onDestroy() and checking this cancellation from the AsyncTask.

Background threads may (or may not) hold a strong reference to something more then it actually should, depending on your usage. I recommend taking a look at WeakReference from java if you are going to pass references from your activity to your background thread or AsyncTask.

Your threading conditions on firing multiple simultaneous AsyncTasks may (or may not) end on a asynchronous or synchronous processing, depending on your platform version.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approach on modifying UI Thread, one of those is push a message to a  handler.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(){

  public void handleMessage( Message msg ){
     //Perform yor UI Modification
  }
```

}

```
handler.sendMessage( msg );
```